# How to convert res from route in json instead of array from callback function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, ajax

I am extracting frames from a video using ffmpeg, as it's callback function returns the path of extracted frames in an array.

But, the response is not transmitting back to ajax success. It is being displayed on the same route only, may be this is because the response i am sending is in form of array.

Need Help on this!!

Code---

```
app.post('/upload',app.upload.single('video-upl'),function(req,res){

    var video_file = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path); // Storing File path
    var video_String = JSON.stringify(video_file); // Converting Json into String of req.file.path
    var video_res = JSON.parse(video_String); // Parsing req.file.path  

    var valueArray = tosplit(video_res.path);  //Splitting Path in values

    var filenme = req.file.originalname; // Requesting Original File name
    var filnameStringify = JSON.stringify(filenme); //Stringify file original name
    var filnameParse = JSON.parse(filnameStringify); //Parsing file Original name

    var filename = extsplit(filnameParse);  // Spliting File name from path

    var finalpath = './public/class/'+valueArray[2]; // Path to Video for Extracting Images

    var destpath = './public/class/'+filename[0]+'/'; //Destinaton Path to Store Images

    var zipdest = './public/class/'+filename[0]; //Destination of File to be Zip

    var articleid = extsplit(valueArray[2]);  //For ArticleId through Video Name

    try {
    var process = new ffmpeg(finalpath);
    process.then(function (video) {
        // Callback mode
        video.fnExtractFrameToJPG(destpath, {
            frame_rate: 1,
            number: 50,
            keep_pixel_aspect_ratio : true,
            keep_aspect_ratio: true,
            file_name : filename[0]+'_%s'
        }, function (error,files){

            if(!error)
                {   
                    var fileJsonStr = JSON.stringify(files);

                    makeZip(zipdest,'./public/class/'+filename[0]+'.zip');

                    console.log(res);

                    res.send(fileJsonStr);
                }
        });
    }, function (err) {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
  }

    catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
});
```

--Ajax Code ---

```
 $('#send_file').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var video_file = $('#video-upl').val();
        var profilehtml = '';


        $(this).ajaxSubmit
        ({
            data: {videofile : video_file},
            datatype: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response){
                for(i=0;i<=response.length;i++)
                    {
                        profilehtml += '<tr>';
                        profilehtml += '<td>'+response[i]+'</td>';
                        profilehtml += '</tr>';
                    }
                    $("#img-bind").html(profilehtml);
            }
   });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean this: `It is being displayed on the same route only`?

Comment: when i am uploading video it moves to /upload route, when i am sending response like res.send(filepath) it is printed on the index.html/upload instead of index.html

Comment: You are not handling the error in API. If API throws an error you need to send to the client also.

Comment: i had written console.log for handling the error as you can see...